# Find the values of a variable for which a series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm practising at solving sequence-series related problems to improve my skills at solving such problems and currently I'm tackling the following problem:

> 1) Find all values of the real variable $x$ for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(x+1)^n}{\sqrt{4^n n}}}$ converges.
>   
>   2) Find all values of the positive constant $a$ for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}}$ converges. For which out of these values does the series converge absolutely?

**My Attempt:**

1. Using Cauchy's Criterion — if $\sqrt[n]a_n \to r < 1$, $a_n$ converges.
   $$
   \sqrt[n]a_n
   = \sqrt[n]{\frac{(x+1)^n}{\sqrt{4^n n}}}
   = \frac{x+1}{\sqrt[2n]{4^n n}}
   = \frac{x+1}{2\sqrt[2n]{n}}
   $$
2. I tried solving this problem in the following ways but both times I got stuck:

   - Using Cauchy's Criterion — if $\sqrt[n]a_n \to r < 1$, $a_n$ converges.
     $$
      \sqrt[n]a_n
      =\sqrt[n]{\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}}
      =\frac{-\sqrt[2n]{n^4+1}}{n^{a/n}}
      $$
   - Using d'Alembert's Criterion — if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to r < 1$, $a_n$ converges.
     $$
      \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
      =\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sqrt{(n+1)^4+1}}{(n+1)^a}\frac{{n^a}}{(-1)^n\sqrt{(n^4+1)}}
      =\frac{-n^a\sqrt{(n+1)^4+1}}{(n+1)^a\sqrt{n^4+1}}
      $$

**Question:**

In all my attempts regarding both sub-problems, I got stuck at some point, which makes me doubt whether I'm using the correct approach of not. How can I solve successfully the above problems?

Comment: In both of these tests, you need to be looking at the absolute value.  That is, $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ and $|a_{n+1}/a_n|$

Comment: My edit was for typos: The subscript $i=1$ on the $\sum$ should have been $n=1$ on the statement of the Q's

Comment: @AngelPolitis Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I've already done so @gimusi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Using Cauchy's Criterion:
$$
\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}
= \sqrt[n]{\frac{|x+1|^n}{\sqrt{|4^n n|}}}
= \frac{|x+1|}{\sqrt[2n]{|4^n n|}}
= \frac{|x+1|}{2\sqrt[2n]{n}}
= \frac{|x+1|}{2e^{\frac{ln(n)}{2n}}}
= \frac{|x+1|}{2e^{\frac{1}{2n}}}
= \frac{|x+1|}{2}
$$

- In order for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ to be convergent, $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \to r < 1$. Therefore:
  $$
  \frac{|x+1|}{2} < 1\Leftrightarrow
  |x+1|<2\Leftrightarrow
  x+1<2 ~~~ \land ~ -x-1<2\Leftrightarrow
  -3<x<1
  $$
- For $x=-3$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges conditionally, because it's an alternating series:
  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n
  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{\sqrt{4^n n}}
  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{2^n\sqrt{n}}
  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}
  $$
- For $x=1$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges, because:
  $$
  a_n
  =\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{4^n n}}
  =\frac{2^n}{2^n\sqrt{n}}
  =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
  =ζ\left(p=\frac{1}{2}\right),~~~ 0<p\le 1
  $$

So, based on the above calculations, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges:

- absolutely $\forall~(-3, 1)$.
- conditionally when $x=-3$.

  ---

**Question 2:**

Using Leibniz's Criterion:

Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}}$ is alternating, it converges, if according to Leibniz's Criterion the sequence $a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}$ is positive, decreasing and its limit is equal to $0$.

- $a_n$ is positive, since both the numerator and denominator are positive $\forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}$.
- $a_n$ is decreasing $\forall\ a$ that make the denominator greater than the numerator:
  $$
  n^a>\sqrt{n^4+1}\Rightarrow
  n^a>\sqrt{n^4},\ \forall\ n\gg 1\Rightarrow
  n^a>n^2\Rightarrow
  a>2
  $$
- $a_n\to 0~~ \forall~a$ that make the denominator $\to\infty$:
  $$
  a_n
  =\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}
  =\frac{n^2\sqrt{1+n^{-4}}}{n^a}
  =\frac{\sqrt{1+n^{-4}}}{n^{a-2}}\to 0\Rightarrow
  n^{a-2}\to\infty\Rightarrow
  a>2
  $$

Because all prerequisites of Leibniz's Criterion are fulfilled, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}}$ converges $\forall~a>2$.
Following that, we observe that:

- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n a_n}$ converges absolutely when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ does, because:
  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}|}
  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}}
  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}
  $$
- $a_n$ is a multiple of Riemann's $ζ$ function:
  $$
  a_n
  =\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}
  =\frac{\sqrt{1+n^{-4}}}{n^{a-2}}
  =\sqrt{1+n^{-4}}\cdot\frac{1}{n^{a-2}}
  =\sqrt{1+n^{-4}}\cdot ζ(a-2)
  $$
  Since, Riemann's $ζ$ function converges only when $p>1$, then, in order for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ to converge $p=a-2>1\Rightarrow a>3$.

Based on the above calculations, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}}$ converges:

- conditionally $\forall~a\in(2, 3]$ and
- absolutely $\forall~a\in(3, +\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, the ratio test gives the limit
$$\frac {|x+1|}{\sqrt {4} }$$

it will converge if $$|x+1|<2$$
or
$$-3 <x <1$$

For $x=1$ it becomes
$$\sum \frac {2^n}{2^n\sqrt {n}} $$
which diverges.
For $x=-3$, it is
$$\sum\frac {(-1)^n}{\sqrt {n}} $$ which converges.

The series converges $\iff  -3\le x <1$.

For the second, as said by Gimusi, the general term is positive and equivalent to $\frac {1}{n^{a-2}} $, so the series converges if $a-2>1$ or $a>3$.

Comment: For Q 2 we have convergence iff  $a>2$ because if $a>2$ the series is  alternating   and the sequence of absolute values of the terms  is "eventually monotonically " converging  to $0,$..... and if $a\leq 2$ the  sequence of the terms of the series does not converge to $0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, I think Salahamam means that $\forall~a>3$, the series converges *absolutely*. The series also converges *conditionally* $\forall~a\in(2, 3]$ as shown in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2688407/find-the-values-of-a-variable-for-which-a-series-converges/2690327#2690327), but, since this answer ignores the fact that the series is alternating, he may have ended up getting a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Let follow the following hint

- for 1 let use ratio test
- for 2 note that $\frac{\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^a}\sim \frac{1}{n^{a-2}}$

Notably for the first by ratio test we obtain the following convergence interval

$$\frac {|x+1|}{\sqrt {4} }\implies |x+1|<2 \implies -3 <x <1$$

and studing a part the limit cases $x=-3$ and $x=1$ we finally find $-3\le x<1$.

For the second by [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum \frac {1}{n^{a-2}}$ we find that the series converges for $a-2>1$ that is $a>3$ and diverges otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gimusi. One thing I don't get about (2): How did you figure that the first is equivalent to the second?

Comment: @AngelPolitisfor n large the numerator is $\sim n^2$. Note that this is only a first estimation (and could also be a guess) that becomes rigorous by the limit comparison test to prove the convergence/divergence range for a.

Comment: @AngelPolitis Note that indeed for n large $n^4>>1$ then $\sqrt{n^4+1}\sim \sqrt{n^4}=n^2$

Comment: @AngelPolitis It is ok (adding the absolut evalue) and now take the limit for $n\to \infty$